# Insert input if it does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on an email template editor where the user will select from a list of pre-existing templates and will be able to update the template as necessary. I had problems with using the CKEditor plugin across browsers and so I have attempted to create my own. When the user selects a template it opens in a modal window. To change the images I have included input tags which are removed upon close of the modal. This works so well and so good but if the user then wants to go back into the editor the input buttons are no longer there.

I want to add in the input button in the modal window if it does not exist. I have tried checking the length of the property but I am unable to return a value other than null whether it exists or not. My code is as follows:

```
function template1InputButtons() {
    if ($("#imageInput1T1").length == 0) {
        $('<input id="imageInput1T1" type="file" name="newImage1T1" onchange="previewImage1T1(this)" />').insertBefore('.article_media');
    }
}
```

If I open it the first time the length comes up as one and so nothing is added as expected. If I remove and then click the button again length shows as 0 and input is added correctly as expected. If I then remove the input and click the button again the length comes up as 1 despite the control not existing.

Any ideas?

Comment: use length as a method..

Comment: Or try using `$("something").val() == ""`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function template1InputButtons() {
    if (!$("#imageInput1T1")) {
        $('<input id="imageInput1T1" type="file" name="newImage1T1" onchange="previewImage1T1(this)" />').insertBefore('.article_media');
    }
}
```

and also assure that you have placed it inside ready function.

Comment: Use `!$("#imageInput1T1").length` in `if` condition. `$("#imageInput1T1")` probably returns an empty array and `![]` doesn't return true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($("body").find("#imageInput1T1").length == 0) {
        $('<input id="imageInput1T1" type="file" name="newImage1T1" onchange="previewImage1T1(this)" />').insertBefore('.article_media');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a similar finding of class attribute article_media on the other modal my mistake thanks for the help anyway